# Error: No named parameter with the name 'List'

Tags: flutter, visual-studio-code

When i run my flutter app on vs code,I get this error :
lib/ui/pages/home_pages/ads_view.dart:65:39: Error: No named parameter with the name 'List'.

```
                                      ^^^^
../../../Desktop/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/painting/gradient.dart:366:9: Context: Found this candidate, but the arguments don't match.
  const LinearGradient({
        ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

and this is the code :

```
Container(
  decoration: BoxDecoration(
    gradient: LinearGradient(
      List: [Colors.black87, Colors.transparent],
      begin: Alignment.bottomCenter,
      end: Alignment.center,
    ),
  ),
)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `colors` property instead of `List`.

```
Container(
  decoration: BoxDecoration(
    gradient: LinearGradient(
      colors: [Colors.black87, Colors.transparent], // Here it is
      begin: Alignment.bottomCenter,
      end: Alignment.center,
    ),
  ),
)
```